# Using jQuery Append and/or templating?

Tags: jquery

Using ajax and jQuery Append() to put some items into a div which is all working well.  My question is can I set up some sort to template for the div instead of having to put all the html code in the Append() line?

Comment: Google **javascript templates** and you'll get quite a few hits. There are tons of libraries, so look through a couple of them and see if they fit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at jQuery templates. It seems like it does what you need.

http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/

See the examples in that page. I think what you are looking for is something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    <li>
        Title: ${Name}.
        {{each Languages}}
            ${$index + 1}: <em>${$value}. </em>
        {{/each}}
    </li>
</script>

<ul id="movieList"></ul>

<script>
var movies = [
    { Name: "Meet Joe Black", Languages: ["French"] },
    { Name: "The Mighty", Languages: [] },
    { Name: "City Hunter", Languages: ["Mandarin", "Cantonese"] }
];

/* Render the template with the movies data */
$( "#movieTemplate" ).tmpl( movies )
    .appendTo( "#movieList" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you meant, but you can pass an object of properties when you create the new element. For example:

```
var divProperties = {id: 'myID', 'class': 'myClass', text: 'Some text'};
$('<div/>', divProperties).appendTo('body');
```

Which would output:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="myClass">Some text</div>
```

[jQuery API - Creating New Elements](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [micro-templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/). A good example can be found in the [TODO app](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) example for Backbone.js.

Basically, the template is in the HTML code:

```
<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
<div class="view">
  <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" <%= done ? 'checked="checked"' : '' %> />
  <label><%- title %></label>
  <a class="destroy"></a>
</div>
<input class="edit" type="text" value="<%= title %>" />
```

And is used very easily in the JavaScript:

```
template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),

render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
  this.$el.toggleClass('done', this.model.get('done'));
  this.input = this.$('.edit');
  return this;
},
```

There are of course many other templating engines.

Answer (score 0):

There are many jQuery and JavaScript templating libraries, my preference is [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Besides the cool name, it is a very efficient, fast, easy to use and adaptable library.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/BP93x/

JavaScript:

```
var tmpl = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById('tmpl').innerHTML);
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = tmpl({
    name: 'Jake'
});​
```

HTML:

```
<script id="tmpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <h1>Hello, {{ name }}.</h1>
    <h2>Handlebars loves you.</h2>
  </script>
<div class="container">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

​Handlebars can also load templates from external files, supports loops and if/else statements.